# Как резко менять значение позиции объекта по x и плавно по y в Unity?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте.
Все действия происходят в Unity(пишу под Android, но думаю разницы не играет особой).
Мне в моём случае надо менять значение позиции камеры относительно игрока,а именно не изменять по z но менять плавно по y и резко по x. Зачем резко по x? Чтобы игрок находился сбоку от камеры. Например игрок идёт вправо, значит он должен находиться с левой стороны камеры, чтобы пользователю было видно препятсвия которые идут перед игроком. И наоборот, игрок движется влево, сам игрок находиться в правой стороне относительно камеры, чтобы было видно препятсвия которые идут слева (надеюсь понятно объяснил). 
И если я сделаю перемещение камеры относительно игрока и по X плавно, и по Y, то камера будет "запаздывать" за игроком, и получиться так, что камера не будет показывать препядствия перед игроком (ествесвенно в зависимости в какую сторону он движется) пока не догонит игрока.

У меня так же были какие-то наброски:

```
private void Update() {
 transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, rocket.transform.position.y, -10f), ref velocity, smoothTime );
        float newPositionX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, rocket.transform.position.x+1f, ref yVelocity, smoothTime );
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPositionX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Ииии:

```
private void Update(){
    if (rocket.transform.position.x < 0)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(rocket.transform.position.x - 1f, transform.position.y, -10f), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
            }
            else if (rocket.transform.position.x > 0)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(rocket.transform.position.x + 1f, transform.position.y, -10f), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
            }// Определяю в какую сторону идёт игрок(я изменял направление спрайта путём изменения значения по X)


            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, rocket.transform.position.y, -10f), ref velocity, dampTime);
}
```

Но ни один из них не увенчался успехом, прошу помочь чем можете, буду сильно благдорен.
Заранее спасибо =)

Comment: обычно если надо следовать игроку назад и вперед, то его помещают посередине.... вы уверены, что постоянные резкие скачки камеры не вынудят игрока стошнить на монитор от резких перепадов?

Comment: Хммм, нуу, я как бы  хотел сделать так, потому что не мог найти(придумать) нормальную функцию для передевижения за игроком, чтобы она не опаздывала и игрок не был быстрее камеры, поэтому решил, чтобы камера не опаздывала за игрком, изменять X более резко, чем Y. Вы, к случаю, не знаете как сделать так как?